# django formset save gives expected string or buffer error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I want to add new table in the database using form set

```
for form in formset:
    blog = Blog()
    blog.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
    blog.save()
```

Now when I do this it gives error saying `expected string or buffer`

But whn i do `print(blog)` befor save it gives me blog object

Whats the issue here ?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace

Comment: TypeError
Exception Value:  

expected string or buffer 
This is all I get when I turn debug to true in url